# In what RON scenario do you get to use Bandirates?

Tags: rise-of-nations

In what Rise of Nations scenario do you get to use the unique Spanish units Bandirates? I have heard that they could also become part of a barbaric group and not just a Spanish nation. I wanted to play using them to see what their strengths and weaknesses were. I know they could become Invisible after a while to opponents. Where is the Bandirates scenario in Rise of Nations?

Comment: I don't see the utility of knowing what scenarios allow you to use a unique unit.  What good does it do you to know which scenarios do or do not allow you to use a specific unit?

Comment: Bandirates are extremely more powerful than regular Gunpowder infantry. The reason that I am asking is because I would like to play in that scenario to try them out (also not to play against them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bandeirantes and Elite Bandeirantes are Unique Units of the **Portuguese** in the Conquer The World Campaign **The New World**. This campaign is only playable with the Thrones and Patriots Expansion, which is included in the Extended Edition on Steam.

[image]

[image]